# Node.js Version Deprecated on Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ok So I have a concern that, while updating the Platform Branch, I couldn't be able to update it. I don't want to implement rolling updates. But unfortunately I'm not be able to update this. Does anyone recently face this issue. Want to updatenode version to (18.x.x) and currently it's (16.x.x)

[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibMTx.png)